# Is foreign based flight-time accepted in Canada?

Tags: flight-training, ppl, transport-canada

I'm currently doing PPL course in Canada. Actually, I have flight times which was logged in my country. Can this flight time used when meeting the requirement for the PPL flight time?

Comment: [Discussion of the question can be found in the Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/tx1ad1/getting_ppl_in_canada_and_flight_times_from_other/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HT @tedder42 for the link to [this redit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/tx1ad1/getting_ppl_in_canada_and_flight_times_from_other/) which shows that ...

It may be accepted in credit towards the Canadian experience requirements.

From [Canadian Flight Regulations](https://tc.canada.ca/en/corporate-services/acts-regulations/list-regulations/canadian-aviation-regulations-sor-96-433/standards/standard-421-flight-crew-permits-licences-ratings-canadian-aviation-regulations-cars#421_26) -

> Division VI - Private Pilot Licence
>
> 421.26 Aeroplanes - Requirements
>
> (9) Credits for Foreign Applicants
>
> (c) An applicant who does not hold a Private or higher pilot licence -
> Aeroplane issued by a contracting state may be credited foreign dual
> and solo aeroplane flight training time and aeroplane ground school
> time towards the knowledge and experience requirements for the issue
> of a Private Pilot Licence - Aeroplane, if the applicant provides
> certification from the holder of a Flight Instructor Rating -
> Aeroplane that all ground and flight training exercises have been
> satisfactorily reviewed.